# Algebraic derivative solution

Tags: calculus, derivatives, gambling

I have a function that I need to find $x$ where the maximum of $y$ occurs.

$$f(x)= 0.00394\log(1+75x)+0.02335\log(1+25x)+0.97271\log(1-x).$$

Using this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ugttrgzwjh), I find $x$ where maximum of $y = -0.002179$.

How to go about finding solving this algebraically? I am not a math heavy guy and never studied calculus but maybe I can follow along with the right direction.

This [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662104/kelly-criterion-with-more-than-two-outcomes) is similar to the one brought up here. I have modified that example for my use case.

If you could help cheers! If not have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Algebraically it might be somewhat annoying because of the logs, but in general, if your function is continuously differentiable, you should try to solve the equation $f'(x)=0$ to find critical points. The intuition behind this is that when a function reaches either a maximum or a minimum, it will change direction, so its slope will change sign and therefore go through 0. Luckily, your function contains only three logs, so you can compute its derivative as
$$\frac {a_1}{1+b_1x}+\frac {a_2}{1+b_2x}+\frac {a_3}{1+b_3x}=0$$
Multiplying both sides by $(1+b_1x)(1+b_2x)(1+b_3x)$ will give you a sum of quadratics which you can then solve with the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). After that just plug the solutions into your original function and compare which one is largest. Alternatively you could try computing the second derivative and using the [second derivative test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html), but that seems like it is more trouble than it is worth.